# Getting caret position in visual studio's editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I am currently developing a Visual Studio extension, that needs to open a WPF form after firing a menuCommand.

I want to open the form relativly to the caret position, so I need to get the Caret's pixel position. 
I've checked [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application)

but it didn't work.

Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've got a IWpfTextView, you can do `view.TextViewLines.GetCaretBounds(view.Caret.Position.BufferPosition)` which will give you the position in the "text coordinate system". Adjusting by view.ViewportTop/view.ViewportLeft should give you the position relative to the UIElement that is the view. From there, view.VisualElement.PointToScreen will probably get it to screen coordinates.

I assume you're already figured out that you don't want to embed this UI into the editor directly? Because that's (mildly) easier.

Comment: Hi jason, thank you so much for your reply! could you help me getting the IWpfTextView of the active document? (not projectItem), furthermore, what do you mean about embeding UI directly to editor?

Comment: It should be `GetCharacterBounds`, not `GetCaretBounds`.